# Probability of drawing multiple cards of the same suit

Tags: probability, card-games

From a standard deck of cards ($52$ cards), you and the dealer take turns drawing a card. The dealer draws the card first. The one who draws $8$ diamonds the fastest wins. Calculate the probability of winning.

On the dealer's first move, he has the probability of drawing a card of the desired suit $\frac{13}{52}$ versus $\frac{39}{52}$ the probability of drawing a card of the other suit.

In our first step, two options are possible, depending on what happened at the dealer:

$1)$ if the dealer pulled out a diamond card in the first step: diamond card with probability $\frac{12}{51}$ versus non diamond with probability $\frac{39}{51}$

$2)$ if the dealer did not pull out a diamond card in the first step: diamond card with probability $\frac{13}{51}$ versus non diamond with probability $\frac{38}{51}$

The dealer's next step must take into account the previous state of the system, and so on. Thus, the outcome tree is doubled at each step.

It seems that there is an asymmetry in the game (due to the fact that the dealer goes first) - a favorable outcome of $1$ round of the game for us is only the outcome in which the dealer does not draw a diamond card, but we draw it out. The remaining outcomes are either in favor of the dealer or are neutral. However, I don't see how to scale this idea to the whole game and how to do without calculating the winning paths.

Comment: What if one player gets $6$ and the other $7$?

Comment: In any case, the outcome is set at the start.  All that matters is the number of diamonds in even positions.  So you want the probability that there are $≥8$ diamonds in even positions.

Comment: The point is that, with a threshold of $8$, there is no race involved.  At most one player has enough of the right sort of diamonds.  Thus the placement of the even diamonds or the odd diamonds is irrelevant.  It would be considerably harder to do the same problem with $6$ diamonds.

Comment: If one player gets $6$ and the other $7$, our player does not win, therefore, outcomes favorable to this scenario do not suit us.

Comment: Ok, so just add the probabilities of getting $≥8$ diamonds in the even slots.  You can save a little time by using the symmetries, but the computation is easy in any case.

Comment: Why do you single out even-numbered positions? It may also be that our player will pull out the 8th card of diamonds, for example, at the 15th step. Maybe I don't understand what you mean by even position.

Comment: Even and odd refer to the positions in the deck, not the rank of the card.  At the start, you have all the even positioned diamonds, and your opponent has all the odd positioned diamonds.  You win if and only if there are at least $8$ even positioned ones.  Note that that there is no advantage to going first. If you were going for $6$ diamonds, there would be.

Comment: I understand, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

Since it is impossible for both players to draw $8$ diamonds, there is no race involved here.  You will win if and only if there are $8$ or more diamonds in even positions at the start of the game.  Thus the probability that you will win is given by $$\sum_{k=8}^{13} \frac {\binom {13}k \times \binom {39}{26-k}}{\binom {52}{26}}\approx .2615$$

Worth remarking that it would be considerably more work to solve the same problem with $6$ diamonds instead of $8$.  In that case, it is possible that both players have enough diamonds in favorable locations to win the game, so the exact locations of the diamonds in the deck becomes relevant.